# ServiceStack.Text with Xamarin Forms

Tags: servicestack, xamarin.forms

Trying to install ServiceStack.Client and VS complains about ServiceStack.Text with the following message

> Could not install package 'ServiceStack.Text 4.0.56'. You are trying
>   to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

Any suggestions on getting past this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Hello Mobile project](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile#portable-class-library-support) shows the list of supported PCL Profiles:

### Portable Class Library support

Most clients make use of ServiceStack's new PCL support which are contained in the following NuGet packages:

- ServiceStack.Interfaces

  - PCL Profiles: iOS, Android, Windows8, .NET 4.0, Silverlight5, Windows Phone 8.1 (Profile 328)
- ServiceStack.Client

  - PCL Profiles: iOS, Android, Windows8, .NET 4.5 (Profile 7)
  - Custom builds: NET40, Silverlight 5
- ServiceStack.Text

  - PCL Profiles: iOS, Android, Windows8, .NET 4.5 (Profile 7)
  - Custom builds: NET40, Silverlight 5

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android do support the **Profile 7** so it looks like the issue is due trying to create a Xamarin.Forms Portable Library Project, as you've discovered it seems the solution is to create a Xamarin.Forms Shared Project instead until we can investigate supporting **Profile 111**.

Comment: I've have changed from a Xamarin Forms Portable Library project to a shared and packages now install.

Comment: Please do investigate supporting profile 111 (I believe that's the profile Friends uses); there are a lot of people using PCL for Forms-based apps.

Comment: Like Andy Hopper said profile 111 is one of the most used. Can't you support it ?